# Got the classnotfoundexception when use the ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader()

Tags: java, classloader

In the tomcat ,I load the HelloWorld by consume class loader.

```
  sb.append("package XXXX.XXXXX.XXXX.freemarkerjob;\n");
        sb.append("import XXXX.XXXXX.XXXX.freemarkerjob.DoStuff;\n");
        sb.append("public class HelloWorld implements DoStuff {\n");
        sb.append("    public void doStuff() {\n");
        sb.append("        System.out.println(\"Hello world\");\n");
        sb.append("    }\n");
        sb.append("}\n");


Class<?> helloClass = InMemoryJavaCompiler.compile("XXXX.XXXXX.XXXX.HelloWorld", sb.toString(), optionList);
```

And I found if I use the Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader() as the DynamicClassLoader's parent, then I can load the class successfully, however IF I  Use (ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader() , It throw classnotfoundexception  when call the method cl.loadClass(className);, which failed to load the interface DoStuff , to which HelloWorld implement it.
what I need to know why SystemClassLoader cannot load the interface?

```
DynamicClassLoader cl = new DynamicClassLoader(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader());


DynamicClassLoader cl = new DynamicClassLoader(ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader());


    Class<?> helloClass = InMemoryJavaCompiler.compile("XXXX.XXXXX.XXXX.HelloWorld", sb.toString(), optionList);



public static Class<?> compile(String className, String sourceCodeInText, Iterable<String> options) throws Exception {

This one successfully 
         DynamicClassLoader cl = new DynamicClassLoader(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader());

This one failed
        //     DynamicClassLoader cl = new DynamicClassLoader(ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader());

 cl.loadClass(className);

}

package XXXX.XXXXX.XXXX.dynamicjava;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
public class DynamicClassLoader extends ClassLoader {
    private Map<String, CompiledCode> customCompiledCode = new HashMap<>();
    public DynamicClassLoader(ClassLoader parent) {
        super(parent);
    }
    public void setCode(CompiledCode cc) {
        customCompiledCode.put(cc.getName(), cc);
    }
    @Override
    protected Class<?> findClass(String name) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        CompiledCode cc = customCompiledCode.get(name);
        if (cc == null) {
          Class<?> curClass = super.findClass(name);
            if (curClass == null) {
                return null;
            } else {
                return curClass;
            }
        }
        byte[] byteCode = cc.getByteCode();
        return defineClass(name, byteCode, 0, byteCode.length);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your interface(DoStuff) is not loaded by SystemClassLoader, usually it is loaded by application class loaders.

If you want to make HelloWorld available in context of DoStuff use following,

DynamicClassLoader cl = new DynamicClassLoader(DoStuff.class.getClassLoader());